# Change an associative array into an indexed array / get an Zend_Table_Row_Abstract as non-associative

Tags: php, zend-framework, associative-array, associative

Hi out there in Stackland.  I was wondering if there was either a function or an easy way to change an associative array into an indexed array.

To elaborate, I'm using the Zend framework, and I've got a point in my site where I take out a row of an SQL table as an associative array.  I've passed it to javascript via an echoed  in JSON.  However, I've noticed that I can see the names of my database's columns in Firebug.  Having outsiders know the names of your tables and columns is a big security no-no, so I'd like to change it from

```
SQLarray[user_id]
SQLarray[block_id]
SQLarray[b_price] etc.
```

to

```
SQLarray[0]
SQLarray[1]
SQLarray[2] etc.
```

Is there a good way to do this?

It would also work to be able to have a Zend_Table_Abstract->fetchAll() return a non-associative array, but I don't think that's possible.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Is pure php ok?

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: If the initial array was generated from odbc_fetch_array, can I count on array_values to always honor the proper column-order of the resultset? It seems like I can.

Answer (score 6):

define function

```
function array_default_key($array) {
    $arrayTemp = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $arrayTemp[$i] = $val;
        $i++;
    }
    return $arrayTemp;
}
```

Pass the associative array as a parameter and it will convert into the default index of the array. For example: we have `Array('2014-04-30'=>43,'2014-04-29'=>41)` after the call to the function the array will be `Array(0=>43,1=>41)`.

Comment: Could you provide a description or brief explanation of how your code solves the problem?

Comment: just pass associative array as parameter and it convert into default index of array. For example: we have Array('2014-04-30'=>43,'2014-04-29'=>41) after call function array will be Array(0=>43,1=>41)

Comment: This logic is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

for multi layered array i use this:

---

```
function getIndexedArray($array) {
        $arrayTemp = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
            $keys = array_keys($array[$i]);
            $innerArrayTemp = array();
            for ($j=0; $j < count($keys); $j++) { 

                $innerArrayTemp[$j] = $array[$i][$keys[$j]];                
            }
            array_push($arrayTemp, $innerArrayTemp);
        }
        return $arrayTemp;
    }
```

it turns this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [OEM] => SG
            [MODEL] => Watch Active2
            [TASK_ID] => 8
            [DEPT_ASSIGNED] => Purchashing  
        )
)
```

into this :

```
[0] => Array
        (
          [0] => SG
            [1] => Watch Active2
            [2] => 8
            [3] => Purchashing  
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple piece of code, if you do not want to use the inbuilt PHP function.

```
$input_array;           // This is your input array
$output_array = [];     // This is where your output will be stored.
foreach ($input_array as $k => $v){
    array_push($output_array, $v);
}
print_r($output_array);
```

Comment: this is the basic solution that everyone would use. but i guess question means if there is a better way than this.